# How to know the called method in Silex

Tags: php, silex

I'm trying to retrieve the method name or the url called in the `authentification` method in a silex class.

This the how I call my method in the connect function:

```
$controllers->get('/list/reviews/', array($this, 'actionAllReviews'))
        ->before(array($this, 'controlerAuthentification'));
```

Before every method i'm calling the authentification function in which i want to get the called method. In my case it `actionAllReviews` or `/list/reviews/`.

```
public function controlerAuthentification(Request $request, Application $app)
{
    if(!$this->getClient()){
        $app->abort(404,'Wrong client informations');
    }

  //How can I get the information here ?
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silex add a `_route` attribute to the `$request` that contains the route name. You can use that.

```
$routeName = $request->attributes->get('_route');
```